# Keep browser extension popup open when a child window is closed via `window.close()`

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension's popup opens a new window via `window.open()`. But when I call close on the new window's reference, it actually also closes both the programmatically created window and the extension's popup itself. The same behaviour happens when I close the new window via keyboard (`Cmd + W` on a Mac), but *not* when I close it with my cursor from the window's `X` (close) button (only the window is closed and the extension remains open then).

This is how the window is opened and closed:

```
const popup = window.open('domain.com/extension', 'Title', params)
window.addEventListener('message', async ({ data }) => {
  if (!data.status) popup.close()
})
```

The same thing happens when the child window itself calls `window.close()`:

```
if (location.pathname === '/extension') {
  window.opener.postMessage({ status: condition }, '*')
  return window.close()
}
```

Is this because of the focus shifting between windows (meaning the window with the extension open temporarily loses focus)? Is there any known workaround for this?

Comment: The popup closes automatically when a different tab becomes focused in this window, there could be other conditions as well. Anyway, this entire approach is fragile because the user can switch tabs or another extension can do it. The reliable approach is to move the logic into the background script and use [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), not DOM messaging, or directly access data via getBackgroundPage ([more info](/a/54715122)). That said, the behavior you described may be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: So I moved the `window.open()` logic to my background script and swapped out `postMessage` with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` via https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage, but even when calling `window.close()` from the background and only on the opened popup, the extension's own popup is also closed.

Comment: @wOxxOm for further context, I need to receive a message in my extension from my web application on another domain.

Comment: 1) I forgot to mention: use chrome.windows.create instead of window.open. 2) Sounds like a job for [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Yup, `externally_connectable` is what I'm now using

Comment: FWIW maybe you can use an iframe.

Comment: @kano did you ever find a solution to this? I feel like I have tried every permutation of opening/closing the new window from popup script, background script, content script, remote content in iframe... tried window.open and chrome.windows.create... always the popup itself is closed when the new window is closed programatically. Root of problem seems to be it's impossible to force-focus the popup window... even calling `chrome.windows.update(... {focused: true})` on the popup window *closes* it.

Comment: I ended up using a hidden iframe, since I only needed to communicate between the page and the extension via messages, sorry  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a hidden iframe, since I only needed to communicate data between the page and the extension via messages.

Just make sure to

1. specify + check the origin of messages
2. Use [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) to specify what origins can embed your website

In the embedded webpage, set up the listener for the extension

```js
const allowedOrigin = `chrome-extension://<your-id>`
const sendAppLoaded = (status: boolean) => window.parent.postMessage({ message: 'app_loaded', status }, allowedOrigin)

export const setupMessageExchange = (isBootstrapped: boolean) => {
  if (!isBootstrapped) return sendAppLoaded(false)

  window.addEventListener('message', ({ origin, data }) => {
    if (origin !== allowedOrigin) return console.error('Invalid origin')
    if (data.message !== 'request_stats') return
    
    window.parent.postMessage(
      { message: 'send_stats', data: { /* ... */ } },
      origin,
    )
  })

  sendAppLoaded(true)
}
```

And in the extension's background script:

```js
const host = `YOUR_HOST`
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.src = host
iframe.style.display = 'none'

const requestSessionFromIframe = () => {
  iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage({ message: 'request_stats' }, host)
}

const removeSessionIframe = () => {
  if (document.body.contains(iframe)) document.body.removeChild(iframe)
  window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage)
}

const receiveMessage = async ({ origin, data }) => {
  if (origin !== host) return
  if (data.message === 'app_loaded') {
    if (data.status) {
      requestSessionFromIframe()
    } else {
      // do stuff
    }
  } else if (data.message === 'send_stats') {
    console.info('stats for days!', data)
    removeSessionIframe()
  }
}

export const getStats = () => {
  removeSessionIframe()

  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage)
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```